# About PHP , ARRAY AND Its Filtering

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this

```
$hello=array(
array 0 (
"USER"=>123,
"uslfd"="kdsf";
),
array 1(
"USER"=>124
),
array 2(
"USER"=>127
)
)
```

Now i want to show user from that $hello and store in varible $x like this

```
$x="123,124,127"
```

Can someone show me the way to do this?

I tried it like this

```
$x="";
for($i=0;$i<count($hello);$i++){
$x.=$hello["$i"]["USER"].",";
}
var_dump($x);
```

is there bettter way?
Regards

Comment: `join(',', array_column($hello, 'USER'));`

Comment: I tried from loop but it says error string to array conversion :(

Comment: Not sure why you guys are down voting a first question of anyone into the ground; we've all been newbies on this site, right?

Comment: @Jack best solution, mention that `array_column` is available since php5.5

Comment: I re ediited question... I don't know what logic should i use so sorry i didn't try anything.. Thanks Jack for understanding .

Comment: array_column not working for me :(

Comment: @Jack Great solution, but `array_column()` is only available in PHP 5.5.0+

Comment: @timclutton Yeah, that's why I wrote it as a comment instead of an answer ;-)

Comment: @Jack i tried it like it? (question edited)

Comment: +1 to counter negatives.  I'm with @Jack on this; try to be a bit more friendly, patient and positive people.

Comment: thanks jack your solution is 1 line ...was looking for that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $hello=array(
        array(
    "USER"=>123
    ),
    array(
    "USER"=>124
    ),
    array(
    "USER"=>127
    )
    );

    $tmp = array_map(function($arr){
        return $arr['USER'];
    }, $hello);
    echo implode(",", $tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$hello = array(
    array (
        "USER" => 123
    ),
    array (
        "USER" => 124
    ),
    array (
        "USER" => 127
    )
);

$x = array();

foreach ($hello as $y)
{
    // show the user.
    echo '<p>' . $y['USER'] . '</p>';
    // store the user.
    array_push($x, $y['USER']);
}

// reduce the new array to a string.
$x = implode(',', $x);

// show the string value of $x.
echo '<p>' . $x . '</p>';

?>
```

Comment: You've got the basic idea right; mapping operations can be done easier by using `array_map()` though, like what user 3831882 has shown.

Comment: @Jack I tried to make this as straight forward as possible, as the OP seems to be a novice.  `array_map()` is a good solution but is a bit more complex to understand.

Comment: @Jack is it good or i should use for loop? as i stated in question?

Comment: @quersfas This answer illustrates the workings of what you're trying to accomplish quite well; that said, I can't make up your mind for you :)

Answer (score 1):

When `array_column` is not avalilable you can try:

```
$x = array_reduce($hello, function($t, $v) { return $t . ',' . $v['USER']; }, '');
// remove first comma
$x = substr($r, 1);
```